# HTML/CSS - Overflow on Mobile and when zooming in

Tags: html, css, mobile, overflow, zooming

I'm currently working on a website and I have one particular issue with responsiveness.
The website looked very good and resized appropriately when I changed the size of the browser window from maximum to minimum. However I did get an issue on mobile devices where the website was cut off at the right and the title text was overflowing. I managed to reproduce the issue in the browser as well by making the window as small as possible and then zooming in until I got a horizontal scroll bar. Scrolling all the way to the right then revealed the issue.

[image]

I tried to fix it for mobile devices by including the following code in my CSS:

```
@media(max-width: 700px) {
    html,body {
        width: 150%;
        height: 200%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
}
```

It did solve the overflow issue but now after initial loading the page on mobile is zoomed in and I have to double tap to reset the zoom. I was unable to find a solution for this issue to reset the zoom automatically.
Also shrinking the browser window on PC with this code in place cuts off the website at the right side when the media query is executed.

Here is the code together with a way to look at the issues. If you want to see the original issue you only need to delete the media query from the top of the CSS file.

https://codepen.io/lapierre-bernard-david/pen/NWqZMqd

I'm very new to web development so I'm pretty sure what I came up with is more of a hack than an actual solution. I'd be very happy about any advice.

As I've seen many people with a similar issue, I did include the often suggested viewport header of course, and I have no fixed width anywhere in my code.

Comment: Try it without `maximum-scale=1.0` in the meta tag.

Comment: @RobMoll Initially I hadn't used this setting, I added it later trying to fix the issue. Removing it does not fix it sadly.